# Duplicate primary key when alternating insert between SQLite and JPA

Tags: java, sqlite, jpa

Table `Section` :

```
secID INTEGER Primary Key
secname TEXT
```

Primary key SQLite will automatically set on `insert` :

```
INSERT INTO Section(secname) VALUES("Default");
```

Class `Section` :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Section\"")
public class Section implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="\"secID\"")
    private int secID;

    @Column(name="\"secname\"")
    private String secname;
    + Getter and Setter
}
```

With SQLite I already inserted two rows. When I insert with Java Persistence API :

```
Section sec = new Section();
sec.setSecname("Test2");
tx.begin();
    em.persist(sec);
tx.commit();
```

it will set `secID` to 0. When I then insert another row I get an error because this time `secID` = 1 which already exists because of the two earlier inserts in SQLite (which auto-incrementing primary key automatically set `secID` to 1 and 2).

How can I avoid this with Java Persistence API?

Comment: you mean "secID" is generated automatically "in datastore" ? set the GeneratedValue strategy to be IDENTITY then perhaps

Comment: Suggestion: get rid of the escaped quotes. `@Table(name="Section")` should suffice. Not that I think this is related to your problem at all, mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your second insert is colliding with the two values (`secID` = 1 and 2) already in the table; I think it's colliding with the value you just inserted (`secID` = 0).

You aren't explicitly setting `secID` anywhere, which means it's 0. So it's inserting 0, over and over.

Change the field `secID` in your class to be an `Integer` and not an `int`, and it should behave as [the SQLite docs suggest](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html), where, when "you try to insert a NULL into an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, the column will actually be filled with an integer that is one greater than the largest key already in the table." (Again, right now you are inserting 0, not `null`.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` on your id mapping should do it.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="\"secID\"")
private int secID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in case someone stumbles into this in 2022 and after.

While the answer by [@Predrag Maric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4074715/predrag-maric) was the one that worked for me, there is a missing step in configuring JPA and the SQLite Dialect in most blog posts or tutorials. After spending a day looking into it, I found a solution to this problem. It turns out that the SQL Dialect has an extremely important missing function which is `hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn()` in the class `SQLIdentityColumnSupport`. This is how it looks like after the addition of the function.

```
public class SQLiteIdentityColumnSupport extends IdentityColumnSupportImpl {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentitySelectString(String table, String column, int type) throws MappingException {
        return "select last_insert_rowid()";
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentityColumnString(int type) throws MappingException {
        return "integer";
    }
}
```

Reference of the implementation of the class [can be found here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-community-dialects/src/main/java/org/hibernate/community/dialect/identity/SQLiteIdentityColumnSupport.java).

After that, once one adds `GenerationType.IDENTITY` as the strategy, SQLite will finally work the auto incremented id through and `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations will work just fine.